# Getting java.lang.StackOverflowError when executing mysql query

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have this exception raised from time to time causing my mysql calls to fail.

```
   Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
           at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
           at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
           at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
           at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
           at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3251)
           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1932)
           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2101)
           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2548)
           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:4916)
   .....
```

I am using mysql jdbc 5.1.7 with c3p0. JVM is running in a linux 64 server.
I found a related bug in mysql jdbc 3.0.7 fixed in version 3.0.8. So I suppose this is not my case.

It seems to be random behaviour since for most executions there is no error, but it happens often every week.
Could this be caused by mysql server communication failure?
Any ideas are welcome

Comment: Looks like some bug in the driver library!

Comment: @Santosh Not necessarily, especially since the stackoverflow occurs inside the java.net classes: if this call has a very deep callstack, then the top call could you just be the drop that overflows the bucket (stack). That or the calling code; which is not in the stacktrace does something wrong and causes the stackoverflow.

Comment: Show a deeper stacktrace or the actual code that causes this StackOverflowError

Comment: This is the root cause and The code is very simple: Connection connection = databaseProvider.newConnection ();
connection.setAutoCommit (false); // This is where the error occurs

Comment: @user1149201 - If you are setting explicit auto commit, did you also test without it?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, may you are right. The error seems in the native method interacting with network layer. So its more likely to be related to network elements and neither java or jdbc driver seems at fault.

Comment: @Ravinder - No, autoCommit always set to false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the cause of the the problem.
Seems that it was due to dropped idle connections in mysql server.
The `autoReconnect=true` in mysql url fixed the issue for me.